# How to clear out rotation of loaded model

Tags: three.js

I have a model, which is displayed in Three.js correctly. Top at the top, bottom at the bottom. However, model has a preset rotation of -1.57 on X axis. It means If I add any new object to the scene, axis of object will be not the same as the model axis. How can clear out or reset this preset rotation so the axis of model and axis of world will match and top will be still at the top? I hope I explained myself clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about to rotate yours model once by 1.57, "burn" this orientation back to the vertices of the model then saving it to new file.

```
   // reset mesh rotation
   mesh.rotation.y = 1.57;

   // make current oreintation, the base of the model
   applyMeshTransformation(mesh);

   // export the model to new blob file (can saved from this to new file)    
   exportObject(mesh)

   function applyMeshTransformation(mesh) {

        // apply local matrix on geometry
        mesh.updateMatrixWorld();
        mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(mesh.matrixWorld);

        // reset local matrix
        mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
        mesh.rotation.set(0,0,0);
        mesh.scale.set(1,1,1);
        mesh.updateMatrixWorld();

   };

   function exportObject(mesh)  {

        var objExporter = new THREE.ObjectExporter();
        var output = JSON.stringify( objExporter.parse( mesh ), null, '\t' );
        output = output.replace( /[\n\t]+([\d\.e\-\[\]]+)/g, '$1' );

        var blob = new Blob( [ output ], { type: 'text/plain' } );
        var objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL( blob );

        window.open( objectURL, '_blank' ); 

   };
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! The thing is I will have to load different models and I'm trying to handle this issue automatically. So, I need to be able to fix it without creating extra objects or even files.

Comment: If i understand you, the only thing you need is to rotate your model? if so, takes only the first line of my answer...

Comment: The model is displayed correctly, so I don't need to rotate it. If I would set rotation to any value, it will be rotated. But that not what I want :) The issue is when I add a new object, it won't match rotation of the model. Sorry, if I could explain it better.